# Allowing the user to save the file from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, download

There are a lot of JavaScript utilities now to allow posting a file in an AJAXified way to the server these days.  Is there any utility that allows streaming bytes to the client and download a file?  Or dues that still have to be a server-side solution?  I'm using .NET.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes and no. HTML5 FileWriter has mediocre support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cross-browser support for accessing the filesystem of the client. You could probably do it with Flash/Java, but a much cleaner solution would be to do it in the server and create a download link for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Brian: What you said about Javascript posting files to a server seems an incomplete statement. Only way javascript can post files to a server is by having the user manually selecting the file he/she wants to upload...

To answer your question...

You should be able to issue some sort of ajax call (to a web service, for example), have the web service read the file into a byte array and return it to the client. On the client side, you would need to assemble the byte array. I would assume you'll have to also set the appropriate response type from the web service call.

[This seems to be something like what you are looking for.](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/07/amf-js-a-pure-javascript-amf-implementation/)

Comment: I'm still talking within the realm of a file upload control, but the Async upload control in the ACT or JQuery Uploadify or other utilities are now able to upload a file to the server using AJAX, is specifically what I'm referring to here.